# Conditional clearing of list in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm having problems with my C# code... VS2010 won't let me compile :(

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
bool listNotNeeded;

if(listNotNeeded && !myList.Any()) //I've tried other ways of verbalizing
    {
    myList.Clear();
    }
```

It refuses to compile... gives the error: InvalidOperationException unhandled. Sequence contains no elements. It should never get here if the list is already empty, and there are other parts of the code which populate it. List population code works fine, already compiled and tested... just this piece broke it for some reason.

EDIT:
I'd like to be able to compile without using an unnecessary try-catch or initializing the list with a starter value if at all possible.

```
    private void UpdateRocket()
    {
        if (rocketFlying)
        {
            Vector2 gravity = new Vector2(0, 1);
            rocketDirection += gravity / 9.8f;
            rocketAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(rocketDirection.X, -rocketDirection.Y);
            rocketPosition += rocketDirection;
            Vector2 smokePos = rocketPosition;
            smokePos.X += randomizer.Next(10) - 5;
            smokePos.Y += randomizer.Next(10) - 5;
            smokeList.Add(smokePos);
            if (smokeList.Count > 20)
                smokeList.Remove(smokeList.First<Vector2>());
        }
        if (!rocketFlying)
            if (smokeList.Count > 0)
                smokeList.Remove(smokeList.First<Vector2>());
        if (rocketPosition.X < 0 || rocketPosition.X > screenWidth || rocketPosition.Y > screenHeight)
            rocketFlying = false;
    }
```

Comment: Add a semi-colon to your bool variable.

Comment: Why does it matter if the list is already empty?  Clearing it again won't do any harm.

Comment: How does it throw an exception if it doesn't compile?

Comment: I love it when I post a comment and its immediately made an answer not by me.

Comment: lol@DarinDimitrov gotta keep moving on.

Comment: -1 why? I have the colon in the code, it's for demonstrative purposes. Did you even read the entire post? My code works except the last part.

Comment: It throws an exception because that's how the VS2010 debug function works.

Comment: `Any` will return false if the sequence is empty so you're probably calling `First` or `Single` somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, there's another part of the code which sequentially removes items using First. Does that mess it up at all?

Comment: @impyre yes, if the sequence contains no elements

Comment: @impyre - `First` doesn't remove items, but it will throw an exception if the collection is empty. You first need to find out where the exception is being thrown and post that. The code you have should not throw unless `myList` is null (or possibly due to concurrent modification).

Comment: I did find where it was being thrown... and I *did* post exactly that and nothing else.

Comment: On what line in that code you just pasted does it thrown an exception?

Comment: A little constructive criticism -- You should really post small, _actionable_ code snippets that highlight your problem to begin with (had you tried your snippet, you would've seen that it did indeed work with minor fixes -- setting values & proper syntax).  The follow-up code just made things worse because it was (a) too big and (b) did not contain the previous snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is somewhere else in the code, that you have not shared with us.

Here are a couple of examples:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
myList.Any();             // Does not throw that exception
myList.Clear();           // Does not throw that exception

myList.First();           // Throws: 
                          // InvalidOperationException unhandled. 
                          // Sequence contains no elements.

myList.FirstOrDefault();  // Does not throw that exception
```

This example runs fine:

```
bool listNotNeeded = false;
var myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

if (listNotNeeded && !myList.Any())
{
    myList.Clear();
}
```

> there's another part of the code which sequentially removes
>   items using First. Does that mess it up at all?

**Yes**, that messes things up. If the list is empty, calling `First` will throw that exception.

**Edit**

I think this is your problem:

```
if (smokeList.Count < 1)
    smokeList.Remove(smokeList.First<Vector2>());
```

You're saying: "if there's less than 1 items left in `smokeList`, get the first item and remove it"

Comment: I really appreciate the constructive help. The reason I didn't post that part is because: 1) I used that statement in the previous build, which compiled & ran fine and 2) VS2010 refuses to compile the new build, highlighting the list.Clear statement and throwing the error.

Comment: What kind of compilation error are you getting? Remember that *runtime* and *compiletime* errors are **different**! It can't thrown an error if it is not running, so, are you running the applicaiton or not?

Comment: Thanks for catching that Filip, I've switched around that statement several times, I must've flubbed it once. Though not the root cause of my problems... I'm posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool listNotNeeded = false; // set a value

if(listNotNeeded && !myList.Any()) //I've tried other ways of verbalizing
{
    myList.Clear();
}
```

Comment: the value is initialized to false to begin with

Comment: you must initialize your value in your case, or calculate your value or pass in parameter of function